# deleteAfter Deleting Record from data table Record is not remove without page load how to do it without page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, datatables

I am trying to delete a record from datatable without reloading all the pages:

```
$(function () {
    $(".btndeletesoftware").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
            data: { Id: $(this).attr('Id') },

            success: function (data) {
                $("#software").dataTable().fnDraw();
                alert("Delete Successfully");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: could you please post also your html code !! to see your page behavior

Answer (score 0):

if you have the selected row feature turned on, it is as simple as

```
      success: function (data) {
             var tbl = $("#software").dataTable();
             // if you have the selected row extension turned on
             tbl.rows('.selected').remove().draw();
            alert("Delete Successfully");
        }
```

If not using selected, give it a row number or row selector as defined here https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

Answer (score 0):

Use **fnDraw(false)**. It will prevent table from re filtering.

```
$("#software").dataTable().fnDraw(false);
```